# Smoothness constraint in Computer Vision

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, 3d-reconstruction

I read a book of **Shape from shading** and I met the equation of "**Smoothness Constraint**". 
I kinda don't understand about the meaning of this equation. Can anyone help me to explain this a little bit?. Thanks you so much for spending your time reading my question.

I want to upload image of this equation but unfortunately, I am a new member so I can not upload a picture and I don't know how to write mathematical formula in here.

Comment: can you find a link to it somewhere, perhaps http://www.cbsr.ia.ac.cn/users/szli/mrf_book/chapter_1/node28.html

Comment: I have tried to search on internet but the explanation is hard to understand for me since I am a beginner of computer vision researcher.

Answer (score 0):

The smoothness constraint (over space) refers to an assumption that pixel values will change slowly as you move in any direction, and they'll likely be close in value to their neighbors.

In the shape-from-shading context, this could mean that the smoothness is over the recovered 3d position. Adjacent pixels should project to locations close in 3d space.